# MediaSession callback is never called

Tags: android, android-mediasession

I've created a simple app with one activity and I create a `MediaSession` in its `onCreate` method

However when I run the application and use external media buttons the callback is never called. Any ideas what I might be missing?

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        this.mediaSession = MediaSessionCompat(this, "TAG")
        this.mediaSession?.setCallback(object : MediaSessionCompat.Callback() {
            override fun onMediaButtonEvent(mediaButtonIntent: Intent): Boolean {
                return super.onMediaButtonEvent(mediaButtonIntent)
            }
            override fun onPlay() {
                super.onPlay()
            }
        })
        val builder = PlaybackStateCompat.Builder()
        builder.setActions(PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_PLAY)
        builder.setState(PlaybackStateCompat.STATE_STOPPED, PlaybackStateCompat.PLAYBACK_POSITION_UNKNOWN, 0.0f)
        this.mediaSession?.setPlaybackState(builder.build())
        this.mediaSession?.setFlags(MediaSessionCompat.FLAG_HANDLES_MEDIA_BUTTONS or MediaSessionCompat.FLAG_HANDLES_TRANSPORT_CONTROLS)
        this.mediaSession?.isActive = true
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement `BroadcastReceiver`. One example here: https://github.com/tutsplus/background-audio-in-android-with-mediasessioncompat/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/tutsplus/backgroundaudio/BackgroundAudioService.java